# How to get the data in specified url in java

Tags: java

i am trying to impleement web crawlling in java using jsoup

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mit.edu/").get();

        if(doc.text().contains("research")){
            System.out.println(URL);
        }
```

Here i am gettig the following information in conslole.[image]

How can i get each url data in categery wise(paragraph data image links etc...)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, please? What, exactly, do you want as your output?

Comment: for example if we take http://jsoup.org/ site i need to get the data in  html attributes category wise like paragraph information,image link ,title etc....

Answer (score 0):

Trim The Url until Http://

String abc = Str.trim("http://");

Now Split the String on (.) dot Basis

String[] aplit = abc .split(".");

Now Declare the Arraylist

ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();

Add the 1st value in Array to ArrayList

arraylist.add(aplit[0]);

Now Sort the Array List

Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());

Now u will get the Output in Descending Order